# Pixel Coordinates, Texture Coordinates and gid within Kernel

Tags: metal

Let's say I have a texture of size `100` in width and `100` in height and dispatch it to the kernel function in `{10, 10, 1}` thread groups and size.

I am having trouble understanding whether `thread_position_in_grid` goes from 0 - 9 or 0 - 99 (as the size of my texture is 100 x 100)?

I am using `float4 c = in.read(gid);` to retrieve the color of the texture, but I would like to know how `gid` is *mapped* to the texture coordinates to retrieve the result which is of type `float4` (would there be cases where it is between pixel (texture?) coordinates?).

I would like to understand in depth how the above works, because what I would like to achieve is to be able to retrieve the exact position as defined by the size of my texture in the kernel function; i.e.:

Dispatch size: `{10, 10, 1}` and texture size 100 x 100; and retrieving values in kernel function:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..., 99.

In summary, how are `gid`, `texture coordinates` and `pixel coordinates` related within kernel function? How are they *mapped* from one to another? I have been reading the documentation and similar questions for the past 4 days, but I have not been successful in obtaining a concrete and authoritative answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you're dispatching a grid of work like this:

```
MTLSize threadsPerThreadgroup = { 10, 10, 1 };
MTLSize threadgroupCount = { 10, 10, 1 };
[computeEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadgroupCount
               threadsPerThreadgroup:threadsPerThreadgroup];
```

Your `gid`, with attribute `thread_position_in_grid`, is probably of type `uint2`, since the domain of the grid is two-dimensional. So far, so good.

`gid` will range from (0, 0) to (99, 99). How you map it to other quantities, including texture coordinates is *entirely up to you*.

For example, say you're not operating on a 100x100 texture, but instead a 300x300 texture, and you want to perform some operation on the lower-right corner. In that case, you might add `uint2(200, 200)` to `gid` before reading/writing the texture, in order to address the region of pixels with coordinates (200, 200) to (299, 299). Other, arbitrary transformations are just as possible.

Basically, specifying the grid dimensions is a convenient way for you to describe the logical shape of the operation you want to perform, while also (through `threadsPerThreadgroup`) allowing you to optimize how much of that work can be executed in parallel.

As for (normalized) texture coordinates, in the simple case where your grid dimensions exactly match your texture dimensions, you can get the normalized coordinates corresponding to a kernel function invocation by dividing by a parameter that is qualified with the `[[threads_per_grid]]` attribute, remembering to cast first to avoid truncation:

```
float2 coords = gid / float2(tpg)
```

where `tpg` is another parameter to your kernel function declared as `uint2 tpg [[threads_per_grid]]`.

Comment: The bit about normalized texture coordinates is correct when *sampling* from the texture (using `in.sample(in_sampler, coords, ...)`, for example). When *reading* a texture as in the original question, that always uses non-normalized texture (a.k.a. texel or pixel) coordinates. To be explicit about some of the other questions: there's no automatic conversion involved between position in grid and texture coordinates; the value you pass is interpreted as texture coords directly. With reading, there's no "in between" texture coords; you're passing integers and those map 1-to-1 to texture coords.

Comment: Good notes, Ken. Thanks for the extra details and clarification.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. So, each thread goes from `0-99` within one _single_ group; is there a way by which we know
which group („instance“) that is being executed (ex: group 2 with its corresponding gid value, group 4…)? In addition,
how about if we wanted to retrieve value from `0 - 9999` in case of a 100x100 texture? Would that be possible? If so, is the texture (and the grid, too) stored row-wise or column-wise)?

Comment: @Unheilig: The grid dimensions are **completely unrelated** to the texture dimensions unless *you* decide to relate them. And, if you do, then you control how they relate by what you do in your code. The grid dimensions are solely determined by what you pass to `-dispatchThreadgroups:threadsPerThreadgroup:`. The texture dimensions are, of course, a property of the texture. WRT your confusion about `gid`: it doesn't go from 0-99 nor 0-9999. It's two dimensional; it goes from (0,0) to (99,99). `tpg` would be (99,99), which is why dividing by it normalizes `coords` to (0.0,0.0) to (1.0,1.0).

Comment: @KenThomases From the documentation, I thought that a grid represented an area that covers the whole texture while a thread group is part of many thread groups within that grid and threads are defined to refer those threads within a single thread group. Also, is it possible for us to retrieve not just (0,0) - (99,99) but the value as a whole (i.e., (0,0)-(9999,9999)) even a single partition goes from (0,0)-(99,99) within kernel? As a result, is it possible for us to find out which group is being executed?

Comment: @Unheilig: Compute functions are general purpose; they are not specific to image processing. Therefore, nothing about them is tied to things like textures or their dimensions. You really need to break your mental fixation that keeps imagining they're related. The grid is an abstract way of dividing up the work. You get to divide up the work in whatever way makes sense to you and the nature of the work. Yes, it's *possible* to use a compute function for image processing. Anyway, I have no idea where you're getting "(9999,9999)" from. Nothing in what we've been discussing has those dimensions.

Comment: The function input with attribute `thread_position_in_grid`, which you've named `gid`, is not relative to the thread group. It's relative to the grid as a whole. If you want to convert it from a two-dimensional coordinate to a linear index, you could do `uint index = gid.y * tpg.x + gid.x;`. That's conceptually `thisRow * rowWidth + thisColumn`.